# skype web sdk suddenly stopped working - redirecting to an error page

Tags: javascript, azure, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

We are facing issue with Skype Web SDK integration with the existing APP registered in our Azure AD. It was working earlier and suddenly stopped working. We have tried to clear the browser cache and new private windows, but no luck. Attaching the screenshot of the error below. Any quick help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

[skype web sdk error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V72se.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Resove this issue, In portal you need to edit the manifest of the native application and set "availableToOtherTenants" flag to true. By default the NEW portal sets it to false (the old portal used to set it to true by default).

Comment: Thanks Hemal, that helped! We can configure this option directly through properties -> Multi-tenanted option without modifying in the Manifest (ofcourse it gets updated in the manifest when configured throuh Properties)